# button enable not working on code behind on aspx page

Tags: asp.net

Here is my aspx code for button

```
<div id="navigationButtons">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="button submit" Enabled="true" />   
                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" name="btnNext" Text="NEXT" ToolTip="Next" runat="server" CssClass="button next" TabIndex="0" OnClick="btnNext_Click" Enabled="false"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnPrev" Text="PREV" ToolTip="Previous" runat="server" CssClass="button prev" TabIndex="2" OnClick="btnPrev_Click" Enabled="true"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnExit" Text="EXIT" ToolTip="Exit" runat="server" CssClass="button exit" TabIndex="3" OnClick="btnExit_Click" />
        </div>
```

here is my code behind

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string selectedAnswers = presentationManager.GetSelectedAnswer(pnlQuestionOptions);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedAnswers))
            {

                questAnsInfo = new QuestionAnswerInfo();
                questAnsInfo = persistanceManager.GetPersistanceDataForModification();
                questAnsInfo.Answer = selectedAnswers;
                Question question = persistanceManager.GetQuestionData(presentationManager.GetCourse().Title, Convert.ToInt32(questAnsInfo.Index));
                string feedBack = presentationManager.GetFeedBack(question, selectedAnswers);
                lblFeedback.Text = feedBack;
                feedbackPanel.Visible =  feedBack== string.Empty ? false : true;
                questAnsInfo.Weight = presentationManager.GetWeight(question, selectedAnswers);
                if (persistanceManager.ModifyToPersistance(questAnsInfo))
                {

                }                

                btnSubmit.Enabled = false; //not working
                btnNext.Enabled = true;   //not woriking
            }
        }
```

In above webform code behind I have set the property of the buttons accordingly. But there is no change in property in aspx page. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: First of all use similiar property order in all buttons, simplify to other people reading of your spaghetti.
 What about UpdatePanels, do all controls: buttons and btnSubmit places on the same updatepanel?

Comment: the buttons are not in update panel. They are outside of the update panel in aspx page.

Comment: Stick the buttons inside an `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: yup.after putting the buttons in update panel it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this: i think this will work...

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
           btnSubmit.disabled= true; 
           btnNext.disabled= false;
         }
```

or you can also try:

```
btnSubmit.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the update panel was not working in my case. I have placed my buttons inside update panel and now it has worked.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

These responses are all very helpful!  I found success by putting asp:button in an update panel - but ONLY after calling the [updatepanelcontrol].update() method.  Important detail.